# What's the name of the keystroke that the streamer uses?

Tags: add-on

[image]

it supports 2.90.1 version. it's not screencast key.
thank you for helping.

Comment: Could you share a link to the video too?

Comment: url is here : https://www.twitch.tv/videos/776176932

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is ScreenCastKeys (from github you can get it, but there is other versions, but that's the name "ScreenCastKeys" there is a compatible version for 2.9, but I don't know if its ready for 2.91)

Comment: thank you to answer. I download this. and done.